# How to populate a DataGrid based on selection in a TreeView

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, binding, treeview

I have a TreeView populated by an XML file as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xdpMusicLibrary" Source="MusicLibrary.xml" XPath="LIBRARY" />

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="hdtTrack">
        <!-- From ... <TRACK><TITLE>Track Title</TITLE> ... -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=TITLE/text()}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="hdtAlbum"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource hdtTrack}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=TRACK}">
        <!-- From ... <ALBUM><TITLE>Album Title</TITLE> ... -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=TITLE/text()}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="hdtArtist"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource hdtAlbum}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=ALBUM}">
        <!-- From ... <ARTIST><NAME>Artist Name</NAME> ... -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=NAME/text()}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TreeView Grid.Column="0" Name="tvMusicLibrary"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xdpMusicLibrary}, XPath=ARTIST}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource hdtArtist}" />
```

I would like the DataGrid to display the node selected in the TreeView (e.g. if I selected an artist, the DataGrid would be filled with every song in every album below that artist in the tree, with the columns: Track Number, Track Title, Artist, Album

The XML is structured as:

```
<LIBRARY>
    <ARTIST>
        <NAME>Artist1</NAME>
        <ALBUM>
            <TITLE>Album1</TITLE>
            <TRACK>
                <NUMBER>01</NUMBER>
                <TITLE>Track1</TITLE>
            </TRACK>
        </ALBUM>
    </ARTIST>
</LIBRARY>
```

Is this possible in just XAML?

Comment: Why don't you want to use code? If you use a code-behind class. you can achieve this easily.

Answer (score 0):

If there was a view model, I would do something like:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=tvMusicLibrary, Path=SelectedItem.Tracks />
```

where the Tracks collection would contain the list of tracks at any node level.

But with loading in XML, I'm not sure, I doubt the following will work:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=tvMusicLibrary, XPath=ARTIST/ALBUM/TRACK Path=SelectedItem />
```